# error using cloud9, meteor and angular, error?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, cloud9-ide

I try use meteor, angular on a cloud9 www.c9.io, and I run the tutorial https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app , when I launch de app nothing happen. the code is the same of the example, and I run the same on local pc, it's works.

> angular warning : angular is not defined, please fix or add /*global
>   angular*/

Comment: Have you included the angular js files within your html script / bundle? Please post a screenshot of where you're seeing this error message